# Switching DC-DC Buck converter voltage feedback

Tags: power-supply, diodes, dc-dc-converter

When using 2 PSs for redundancy purposes we connect positive outputs through diodes, as I understand. Is it possible to connect voltage feedback network of the buck converter to diodes cathode, to let the IC compensate diodes voltage drop?

Comment: Depends. Your diode is literally one-way, so the "slope" of your voltage ripple looks a bit different. Sometimes this upsets your regulation loop at light load.

Comment: You think a better way will be to connect feedback network to anode and tune the voltage counting diode drop?

Comment: Again, it depends. You will regain stability for some converters but loose some load regulation. If your loop on the other hand is happy all over the load range after the diode, go for it. How will you do load sharing?

Comment: I need redundancy. I plan just to connect both PSs. My load will be max 0.5A, PSs can do 2A.

Comment: Good. Then it should be just the loop stability you need to worry about.

Comment: The PSU redundancy is a pretty important topic in general computing and servers in particular. What kind of studies did you digest before coming to this simplistic idea of running two supplies with diodes?

Comment: I am powering a flight controller on a drone. Just need a backup power supply in case of failure.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a switch without voltage drop, you need to use ICs that implement so-called "ideal diodes", look at "intelliMAX" line of switches from Fairchild/ONsemi, like [**FPF1320**](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FP/FPF1320.pdf). See a bit longer answer [**here**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/321927/117785).